# What is the difference between GetRoleCredentials and AssumeRole?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I'm fiddling around with writing some code that goes through the STS authentication process. What I have found is that I can call the following API's in sequence:

```
RegisterClient
StartDeviceAuthorization
CreateToken
ListAccounts
ListAccountRoles
```

and I eventually get to the point where I can call `GetRoleCredentials` and successfully get back an `accessKeyId`, `secretAccessKey` and `sessionToken`. I've noticed is that I can use these three values to successfully call a bunch of APIs (eg. get a list of lambda functions).

However, all of the doc I read suggests that I actually should also be calling `AssumeRole` (which also returns `accessKeyId`, `secretAccessKey` and `sessionToken`).

I'm just trying to figure out what the differences are between `GetRoleCredentials` and `AssumeRole`, and when should I be calling one vs. the other. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[GetRoleCredentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/singlesignon/latest/PortalAPIReference/API_GetRoleCredentials.html):

> Returns the STS short-term credentials for a given role name that is assigned to the user.

[AssumeRole](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_AssumeRole.html):

> Returns a set of temporary security credentials that you can use to access AWS resources that you might not normally have access to. These temporary credentials consist of an access key ID, a secret access key, and a security token.

The main differences are **which entity** runs API **to get/know what**.

- SSO service does `GetRoleCredentials` to get the credentials in the role of a user.
- IAM user does `AssumeRole` to get temporary credentials. (And also can know credentials the user get.)

Seemingly SSO operations are running in your case, so I think using `GetRoleCredentials` is OK.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Prior to posting, I'd read both those links multiple times, but it still doesn't explain /why/ I'd choose to use one vs. the other. Debugging the AWS CLI, I can see that it actually calls both but it is unclear to me why.

Comment: For the success of SSO sign-in, SSO service must confirm the user have the credentials. This is done in two steps *with different entities and API*. 1. The user gets *the role with the credentials* via `AssumeRole`. 2. SSO service confirms *the user's credentials in role* via `GetRoleCredentials`. I guess in the CLI the steps are included in the sequence.